# Role of $\mu (A) < \infty$ in Lusin's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to  prove that why $\mu (A) < \infty$ is important in Lusin's theorem  stated as follows:

[image]

Moreover, I want to see if we take $\mu (A) = \infty$
Let  $\mu (A) = \infty$.  Take $A = \mathbb{Q}$ with the counting measure. So, $\mu (\mathbb{Q}) = \infty$.  Let $f = \chi_\mathbb{Q}$. So, clearly the condition of $f$ in theorem is satisfied.

Now I want to prove that there is no function $g \in C_C(X)$ such that $$\mu (\{x \mid \chi_\mathbb{Q} (x) \neq g(x)\}) < \epsilon$$ does not hold.

But I cannot proceed further. Please help.

NOTE: Here $C_C(X)$ set of all complex valued continuous functions on $X$ with compact support and $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff space.

Answer (score 3):

For the counting measure $\mu (E) <\epsilon$ (with $0 <\epsilon <1$) implies that $E$ is the empty set. So you get $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ which says that $f$ is itself a continuous function,  a contradiction.

Comment: But, I am working with the above example ($\mu (A) =\infty$).

Comment: @user1138886 I should not have used $A$ in my answer. I have edited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am eager to see what if $\mu (A) = \infty$.

Comment: I don't understand. In your example you have $\mu (A)=\infty$. @user1138886